# PHP AWS SDK | How to create signed URL with custom domain

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, amazon-cloudfront

I'm using AWS SDK with Laravel framework in PHP. Here is my code

```
$cloudFront = new CloudFrontClient([
    'region'  => env('AWS_REGION'),
    'version' => 'latest'
]);

$path = "R180417XXXX.mp4"

$resourceURL = "https://dbk93n3xxxxxx.cloudfront.net/" . $path;
$expires = Carbon::now()->addMinutes(5)->timestamp;

$signedUrlCannedPolicy = $cloudFront->getSignedUrl([
    'url'         => $resourceURL,
    'expires'     => $expires,
    'private_key' => base_path('pk-APKAI2PXXXXXXXXXXXXX.pem'),
    'key_pair_id' => 'APKAI2PXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
]);
```

This code is working but the URL it look like this

```
https://dbk93n3xxxxxx.cloudfront.net/R180417XXXX.mp4?Expires=1524389577&Signature=RmBDMqM4SMadsQstrgVpUiLoJ50dvKoxNI081Joa7WjSg5eelziQqtDrcs~klbDHvs7rMaq2McfHUQijrcLe7F9tDbn7oOxEC4kfPPCMbhqqjtBWavPmM8Zv8QhH50dPuNHwnEj4pIGUpm9FmAvDhCSExCv0uBMWUREJ9YKQJFHZcPJyKBtjPcJVzIGpnj2bQn3xNGO5AUlutsyeSWUqdvtNOLb3xurgx4WzcVotgB~BZo-bQxo3ieXFbKWAPQXMPl93YpuX5W10l4YtYPULrAtJVQZKUIFcfifnECnqg~IgtbkFbyLdM5e87ZiC837Hj-AphmlEshnY-MHWyEU24g__&Key-Pair-Id=APKAI2PXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

But I'm just setting CNAME in CloudFront like `server1.domain.tld` I want the signed URL show like

```
https://server1.domain.tld/R180417XXXX.mp4?Expires=1524389577&Signature=RmBDMqM4SMadsQstrgVpUiLoJ50dvKoxNI081Joa7WjSg5eelziQqtDrcs~klbDHvs7rMaq2McfHUQijrcLe7F9tDbn7oOxEC4kfPPCMbhqqjtBWavPmM8Zv8QhH50dPuNHwnEj4pIGUpm9FmAvDhCSExCv0uBMWUREJ9YKQJFHZcPJyKBtjPcJVzIGpnj2bQn3xNGO5AUlutsyeSWUqdvtNOLb3xurgx4WzcVotgB~BZo-bQxo3ieXFbKWAPQXMPl93YpuX5W10l4YtYPULrAtJVQZKUIFcfifnECnqg~IgtbkFbyLdM5e87ZiC837Hj-AphmlEshnY-MHWyEU24g__&Key-Pair-Id=APKAI2PXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

I'm have been tried to change `$resourceURL` to

```
$resourceURL = "https://server1.domain.tld/" . $path;
```

It's  not working.

It's response status code `403` and I has been set `Origin Access Identity` I don't know why not working

Here is my `Amazon S3 Policy`

```
{
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Id": "PolicyForCloudFrontPrivateContent",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::cloudfront:user/CloudFront Origin Access Identity E2OP22ZEXXXXXX"
            },
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::server1.domain.tld/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Please help...

Thanks

Comment: What you are attempting *is* supported.  You need to be more specific when you say "it's not work[ing]." What happens when you do this?  If you get an "Access Denied" response, please show the complete error response.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot I updated my post please check out.

Comment: Please post the *complete* error response.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Thanks for try to help me. Now I'm not use signed URL and I use WAF instead. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Route53, there needs to be a hosted zone for your tld and a record set of type CNAME that is an alias to Cloudfront distribution.

Here are steps to follow:

- Create certificate in Certificates Manager for *domain.tld* and *server1.domain.tld*.
- Edit your Cloudfront Distribution Settings and set SSL certificate for the distribution to the custom one.
  [image: Set SSL Certificate for Distribution]
- Ensure that Alternate Domain Names (CNAMEs) for your distribution lists *server1.domain.tld*

[image: List Alternate Domain Names for Distribution]

- [Create Public Hosted Zone](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/CreatingHostedZone.html?console_help=true) for domain.tld in Route53
  [image]
- Copy 4 Nameservers and update your domain registrar to point to them if domain name wasn't setup originally in Route 53
  [image: Copy 4 Nameservers]
- [Create Record Set in the Hosted Zone for a CNAME alia](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/routing-to-cloudfront-distribution.html)s that points to Cloudfront Distribution.
  [image: Create CNAME alias]
- Finally, rest easy and see changes propagate to name servers et Viola!